# Cannot access an XAML class-instance from code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created an class which will be the DataContext for my app, and instantiated it via XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.UI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:myDataModel="clr-namespace:MyApp.MyDataModel"
    Title="MainWindow">
<Window.Resources>
    <myDataModel:MyDataClass x:Name="the_DataModel" x:Key="a_DataModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

I want to act on this object in the constructor of my Window:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    the_DataModel.LoadFromFile(); // One of these *should* work!
    a_DataModel.LoadFromFile();
}
```

However it seems that neither name (`the_DataModel`, nor `a_DataModel`) is a member of the Window class.   When I type `this.`, and use auto-complete, I cannot find anything that resembles the object I created in XAML.

**How can I create an instance of a class in XAML, and access it in code?**

Answer (score 2):

Since you have added it as a resource in window resources, you can **`get it from Resource collection`** by indexing with resource key.

```
MyDataClass dataModel = (MyDataClass)Resources["a_DataModel"];
dataModel.LoadFromFile();
```

Comment: That sounds pretty good.   Are there other ways to add it to the Window that may be more convenient?

Comment: That's a data class instance. How you want it to be rendered on UI? Data objects goes under resources section only and UI components go directly under Window section.